# Storing HTML 5 LocalStorage using PHP serverside

Tags: php, javascript

I've created an account verification system where a user clicks a link in their emailbox which will trigger activate.php, a script which will do some stuff backend in a MySQL db and then present the user with their account. Currently, I'm doing this with a header change:

```
header( www.mydomain.com/useraccount.html);
```

**The problem:** I need certain local storage variable to be set, such as sessionStorage.email and sessionStorage.accountID. I can't be sure that these things are currently set because the user could have closed their browser, clicked activate.php after 20 min. and opened a new session. Therefore I'm wondering how to set HTML 5 local storage variables using PHP. Is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ending up using URL params: `header(www.mydomain.com/useraccount.html/usertag=blah&email=blah@gmail.com);`

and capturing them in Javascript upon page load.

Answer (score -1):

Embed the JavaScript code to set the localstorage into the page that your `activate.php` sends to the client. This could be a short dummy piece of html that runs that JavaScript logic and then does a clientside redirect to `useraccount.html`.

Make sure you provide a fallback if javascript is disabled (i.e. an explicit link).

Comment: right but how would I include the email and usertag in an HTML page? Like header(www.mydomain.com/useraccount.html/usertag=blah&email=blah@gmail.com); ???